# Windows 10 Pro as RDP Host with SSL Certificate. How?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop, windows-10

I have exhausted my patience looking for how to add an SSL certificate to my Windows 10 Pro machine so that when I connect from another place, I don't get certificate errors.

So far, every guide I run into eventually turns out to be for Windows Server.

What I've tried:

I click on start menu then type `certlm.msc` and hit Enter.

I place my purchased certificate in the Host Machine's `Personal > Certificates` folder AND the `Remote Desktop > Certificate Service` folder.

[image]

When I try to reconnect from another machine, I still get the certificate trust error.

Can anyone help?

**Again, I am trying to accomplish this in a Windows 10 Pro machine, NOT Windows Server.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On client, same rules apply. You have to assign certificate to RDS configuration. For example, using PowerShell:

```
$path = (Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").__path
Set-WmiInstance -Path $path -argument @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="THUMBPRINT"}
```

where `THUMBPRINT` is a thumbprint of your certificate. These commands must be executed in elevated shell.

Comment: Crypt32, this worked. I will be posting the complete steps soon. Does the certificate has to be install in both stores or only one? And which one?

Comment: Either, Remote Desktop Certificates or Personal (both Local Machine) are just fine. You don't need to have it in both. Which one -- depends on a maintenance tools and strategie. In iother words -- where it is easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows 11 Pro - Remote Desktop SSL Certificate Setup

##### Based on Articles: [Remote Desktop listener certificate configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-listener-certificate-configurations) and [Rdpsign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753982(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

1. Buy `remote.example.com` [RapidSSL® DV Certificate](https://www.thesslstore.com/rapidssl/rapidssl-certificates.aspx) powered by [Digicert®](https://www.digicert.com) from [SSL Store](https://www.thesslstore.com)
2. Use **OpenSSL** to Generate **RSA Private Key** & **Certificate Signing Request** for `remote.example.com`

   ```
   openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes \
   -out /home/user1/remote_example_com_csr.txt \
   -keyout /home/user1/remote_example_com.key \
   -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/L=Salt Lake City/O=Example, Inc./CN=remote.example.com"
   ```
3. Use **Certificate Signing Request** file `remote_example_com_csr.txt` to Generate **SSL Certificate** at [SSL Store](https://www.thesslstore.com)
4. **Verify Domain Ownership** using DNS Records:

   2.1 Create **A** record where **Host** = `remote`*.example.com* and **Value** = `YOUR_PUBLIC_IPV4_ADDRESS`

   2.2 Create **TXT** record where **Host** = `remote` and **Value** = `hs8s67k8g2y57ptjtt34rfhn0wl7ys6f`. This is provided by [SSL Store](https://www.thesslstore.com) for DNS based domain verification.
5. Use **OpenSSL** to **Combine SSL Certificates** into a **PKCS #12** file.

   ```bash
   openssl pkcs12 -export \
   -out /home/user1/remote_example_com.pfx \
   -inkey /home/user1/remote_example_com.key \
   -in /home/user1/remote_example_com.crt \
   -certfile /home/user1/certificate.bundle
   ```

   > **Note**: You will be prompted for an Export/Import Password. This can be left blank but for obvious reasons it SHOULD NOT be left blank.

   ```
   Enter Export Password:
   Verifying - Enter Export Password:
   ```
6. File `remote_example_com.pfx` is **saved to a secure location**.
7. Use `certlm.msc` to Import **PCKS #12** file into **Personal** > **Certificate** store.

   > **Note**: Before you run the `wmic` commands, the certificate that you want to use **must be** imported into the **Personal certificate store of the local machine**. If you do not import the certificate, you will receive an **Invalid Parameter** error.
8. Start Menu > Type `certlm.msc` and hit Enter.
9. Navigate to Personal > Certificates store.
10. Right-click > All Tasks > Import...
11. Follow Wizard to import SSL Certificate.
12. Double-click SSL Certificate, click **Details** tab to find the certificate **Thumbprint** Field.
13. Copy the thumbprint to Note Pad.

    ```bash
    b363f15095137d374f78d11913a186c5c3ddd44c
    ```
14. Using **command prompt** as **Administrator**, run the following `wmic` command together with the thumbprint value that you obtain in step 13.

    ```
    wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSGeneralSetting Set SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="b363f15095137d374f78d11913a186c5c3ddd44c"
    ```
15. If successful, the following output is shown.

    ```
    Updating property(s) of...
    Property(s) update successful.
    ```

#### Remote Desktop Protocol (.rdp) file

##### Based on article: [Supported Remote Desktop RDP file settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files)

##### Based on article: [mtsc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc)

Creates connections to Remote Desktop Session Host servers or other remote computers and edits an existing Remote Desktop Connection (.rdp) configuration file.

**To open new** Remote Desktop Connection for editing:

```bash
mstsc
```

**To connect from command line** directly on **port** `25301`

```bash
mstsc /v:remote.example.com:25301
```

> **Note**: Generally, your DNS hosting provider does not allow for custom ports to be set with the DNS **A** Record created for `remote.example.com`. To address this limitation, **Port Forwarding** is setup in your **Wireless Router**.

[image: PORT FORWARDING]

> See Wikipedia's [List of TCP and UDP port numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) to make sure you
> **choose a port that is not going to conflict** with any existing service. **Do NOT use default port** `3389` as the External Port.

**To edit existing** `remote_example_com.rdp` file

```bash
mstsc /edit remote_example_com.rdp
```

#### RDP Signing

##### Based on article: [Rdpsign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc753982(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

16. Digitally sign a Remote Desktop Protocol `.rdp` file.

```perl
rdpsign /sha256 f6f6622c5f0a8ad0b7fabf0f37e32bc4922172fb remote_example_com.rdp
```

> The hash value represents the SHA1 certificate thumbprint, without any spaces.